# rvm-exec: not found while building docker

Tags: ruby, docker, docker-build

I have ruby application running inside docker.I tried to run docker container on ubuntu VM which worked fine.But when I tried to run the same docker-ruby application on another VM ,it is giving me error as-

```
Step 14/17 : RUN bundle install --gemfile test/Gemfile
 ---> Running in b545e371e3
/usr/bin/bundle: 2: exec: /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-exec: not found
ERROR: Service 'test' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install --gemfile test/Gemfile' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I'm using same repository and ruby version(1.8.7) on both ubuntu systems, still facing issue.Can anyone help/suggest some solution on this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest not using `rvm` or any similar version manager with Docker.  Just install the single specific version of Ruby your application needs in the image.

Comment: @DavidMaze - Thanks for your response.I would have done that but I have other application too running on same machine which uses different ruby versions,so I'll have to keep RVM. Any alternate solution?Or can I restrict RVM access to docker?

Comment: “Other application ... different Ruby versions”...then you can build a different image, with a different Ruby base, for that other application.

Comment: @nik You can use `rvm` (or better `rbenv`) on your machine but use a fixed version of ruby inside your container (use ruby images).

Comment: @nik Did you solve this issue?